# Appium install on linux

Tags: appium, appium-ios, appium-desktop

Saw so many videos in YouTube but I cannot install the appium, 
I want to install appium server n appium desktop app in Linux
Is it possible??
I’m using both in windows but li Linux I can’t please help me

Answer (score 1):

Download Appium Desktop for linux from : [Offcial Appium site](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/).

You need to download the file with **.AppImage** extension.

Then open terminal and type

```
 chmod a+x filename.AppImage

 ./filename.AppImage
```